# How pass React prop to CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a problem - I don't know how to change checkbox color using a color value from props. My idea was to give it via style attribute but I don't know how to toggle this. I'm using [rc-switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-switch) and I want to change his background depending on Switch state. I have something like this now

```js
<Switch style={{ backgroundColor: mainColor }}/>
```

but it set this color for both states and I want this swich to become 'defaultColor' when is in off position.

Comment: There is no `style` prop on the Switch Component, but there is a `className` prop, which you can use to add your custom class.

Answer (score 8):

> There is no style prop on the Switch Component, but there is a className prop, which you can use to add your custom class.

If you are using sass:

```
.mySwitch {
  &-black {
    background-color: black;
  }

  &-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Then programatically switch the class.

```
<Switch className={`mySwitch-${color}` ... />
```

Could be an option, I think.

Comment: [The `<Switch>` component passes props to the underlying `<span>` that it renders](https://github.com/react-component/switch/blob/master/src/Switch.jsx#L81). So `style` will work nonetheless. The question was about how to set different styles based on the state of the switch.

Comment: Thats true, but I would't rely on undocumented features, they could stop the props propagation anytime

Comment: @webdep But that is also true for the `className` prop. Who garantees that they will not stop to propagate this?

Comment: Yes, exactly like @trixn said I have a problem with changing this depending on Switch state and would like to avoid use Switch `onChange` attribute because I'm using it to another purpose and mix 2 functions there would be too complicated.

Comment: Because this is documented, and they cannot just remove it, because its actually the public API, which should't change without explicit deprecation warning IMO

Comment: I'm using Stylus but anyway I can't operate on classes because I don't know this color - it comes from props.

Comment: Sorry @Alwox, I dont know why its not updating, could you show in your Post, how you are updating the `mainColor` in your state?

Comment: @webdep okay convinced :). `className` is probably better to use for this reason. But that does not solve OP's question how to switch classes depending on the switch's state.

Comment: mainColor come to this component via props as I said `const {mainColor} = this.props;` <- this i have in render

Comment: Just to be sure, that the new props are reaching the Switch component, have you tried to log them? Because I don't see a reason, why the style is not updating..

Comment: No, sorry maybe I was explaining this bad - Switch background color becomes of  mainColor, but I also want default color (i know this color) for switch-off position.

Comment: @Alwox I dont know whats not working here check out this bin https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ko3m50xc6wKNwUOlMv3
You can set the color with the input field and it gets propagated as expected. So check your props, and the code of the component

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a callback to your `<Switch>` component and then handle that event. You could write a component that wraps the original `<Switch>` and switches color when it's state changes. It could look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Switch from 'rc-switch';

class ColorChangingSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {checked, defaultChecked} = props;
    this.state = {
      checked: checked || defaultChecked || false;
    }
  }

  onChange = (checked) => {
      // update your state
      this.setState({
      checked: checked,
    });
    this.props.onChange(checked);
  }

  render() {
    const {onChange, className, checked, ...otherProps} = this.props;
    const colorClassName = this.state.checked ? 'green' : 'red';

    return (
      <Switch
        {...otherProps}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        checked={checked}
        className={`${className} ${colorClassName}`}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ColorChangingSwitch;
```

This is just a basic example. I didn't test it. You can still pass `onChange` to that component and react to it with whatever you want. Also you could add a prop that defines which colors/classes it should set depending on it's state instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: Thank you, but I forget to tell that the problem also is I have more those switches there : / It looks like it is more complicated then I was I had hope that I miss some simple way to do that because this component is complicated anyway and I don't want to shadow this code more..

Comment: @Alwox if you abstract it like in my example you can render as many of those switches as you want with no extra work.

Comment: Maybe you are right, thanks - I'll check it tomorrow and write.